# Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259. - XML Column

Tags: sql-server, xml, sqlcmd, sp-send-dbmail, outer-apply

I keep getting this error

> Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259

when I try to execute the following SQL code. This is a normal query and not through SQL Server Agent.

```
declare @SQL varchar(8000)
set @SQL = 'select a.b.value(''(../../@ID)'',''varchar(100)'') as [System-ID]
            from [DB].[Schema].[Configuration] R
            outer apply R.[Configuration].nodes(''root/System/Role/Authorization'') as a(b) 
            where R.[Report ID] = ''IT.00004'''

print @SQL

exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'servername',
    @recipients = 'info@company.com',
    @subject = 'Test B',
    @query = @SQL
```

However, when I modify the query as followed everything works fine.

```
declare @SQL varchar(8000)
set @SQL = 'select *
            from [DB].[Schema].[Configuration] R
            where R.[Report ID] = ''IT.00004'''

print @SQL

exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'servername',
    @recipients = 'info@company.com',
    @subject = 'Test B',
    @query = @SQL
```

So the problem must be with this part of the statement (I am referencing an XML column called "`Configuration`" in the table "`Configuration`" -> Column name and table name are the same):

```
outer apply R.[Configuration].nodes('root/System/Role/Authorization') as a(b)
```

When I run both queries outside of the `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail` syntax they both run perfectly fine.

Does anyone know what is going on? I doubt that it is permission related since the part that is causing the problem is using the same table that doesn't cause any issues.

Comment: Have you looked at this post: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/104156/sqlcmd-error-failed-to-initialize-sqlcmd-library-with-error-number-2147467259

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to resolve this issue I had to add the following to the query:

```
set @SQL = 'SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON '
set @SQL = @SQL + char(13)
set @SQL = @SQL + 'select a.b.value(''(../../@ID)'',''varchar(100)'') as [System-ID]
            from [DB].[Schema].[Configuration] R
            outer apply R.[Configuration].nodes(''root/System/Role/Authorization'') as a(b) 
            where R.[Report ID] = ''IT.00004'''
```